# Internet Sharing on OS X Mavericks stopped working

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, mac, internet, lan

I have an iMac with OS X Mavericks (10.9) installed. I've been using the Internet Sharing feature to connect to other devices regularly, but since last week the Internet Sharing option has stopped working properly and I can't connect other devices (laptop, smartphones, consoles, etc).

[Wi-Fi interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQci2.png)
[Wi-Fi TCP/IP settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cG5yk.png)

I have everything set accordingly. The Wi-Fi is enabled and recognized in my devices but I can't seem to access the internet through them. It has a self assigned IP address and it's not able to connect to the internet. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Show how you have Internet Sharing configured. Maybe you accidentally swapped the "From" and "To" interfaces last time you turned it on.

Comment: It's checked and set from Ethernet to Wi-Fi.